# How to handle No mapping found for field in order to sort on exception in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am learning Elastic Search.I am trying to fetch data from elastic search.Just after creating index whenever I am trying to get data by providing one field for sorting then I get the exception

> Exception while invoking: ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]]

Reason:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "No mapping found for [startTime] in order to sort on",
                "index_uuid": "--9dlmIUSZiTK9qeuwnZvQ",
                "index": "lm-traces-cg8-000041"
            },
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "No mapping found for [startTime] in order to sort on",
                "index_uuid": "etO6DFeQQp2-bXyEfc3vPA",
                "index": "lm-traces-cg8-000042"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "can_match",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "lm-traces-cg8-000041",
                "node": "y4xzbQrcTUKwUipfJ8vBNA",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "No mapping found for [startTime] in order to sort on",
                    "index_uuid": "--9dlmIUSZiTK9qeuwnZvQ",
                    "index": "lm-traces-cg8-000041"
                }
            },
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "lm-traces-cg8-000042",
                "node": "y4xzbQrcTUKwUipfJ8vBNA",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "No mapping found for [startTime] in order to sort on",
                    "index_uuid": "etO6DFeQQp2-bXyEfc3vPA",
                    "index": "lm-traces-cg8-000042"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I want to catch this exception in java. for now I did

```
 catch (ElasticsearchStatusException e) {
                if(e.getMessage().contains("search_phase_execution_exception")) {
                    logger.error(" No mapping found for field in order to sort on  :  "
                                    + e);
        }
```

But here I want to check only for "**No mapping found**" specifically instead **search_phase_execution_exception** as it might include other exception which should not suppressed. How can I do this.